# Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My html :

```
 <form action="rent.php" method="post"><pre>
        Email : <input  type="text" name="email">
        Message : <input type="text" name="msg_text">
                <input type="submit" value="Rent it">
    </pre></form>
```

My rent.php file :

```
<?php
 require_once 'login.php';
   $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
}
    $query = "SET NAMES utf8";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die($conn->error);
    }

    $req = $conn->prepare('INSET INTO renter (email, msg_text) VALUES(?, ?)');
    $req->execute(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['msg_text']));

    header('Location: menu.php');
```

My error when I try to submit, is : Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:...\rent.php on line 18

email, msg_text are in varchar type

Comment: Just a real bad typo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`mysqli->prepare` can also return `FALSE` (check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) if an error occurred. Your problem is that you have `INSET` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: I did similar mistake - there was a typo in the table name.

Answer (score 8):

This may help someone:
I was facing same issue.
In my case, i have missed to close first prepared statement before executing second prepared statement.

When i have added `$select_stmt_type->close();` before executing second prepare statement, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add. Similar error comes when the mysql column name is incorrect in php. I found below error for my condition when i printed the $conn->error.

> errno: 1054, error: Unknown column 'xyz' in 'field list'

Comment: I faced this issue too but this answer helped

Comment: @Tony sometime we are so much into large things that we forget a minuscule  mistake :-)

Comment: you're right..!

Answer (score 1):

To catch errors do something like this

```
    $req = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO renter (email, msg_text) VALUES(?, ?)');
    if(!$req){
       echo "Prepare failed: (". $conn->errno.") ".$conn->error."<br>";
    }
```

since prepare returns a boolean. Please use when debugging you code and refer to [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) as stated in the comment.

Comment: Please don't. Echoing the error message right away is wrong on so many levels. Please kindly read my [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL prepared statement needs to be corrected as *shudent* said, but I think you also have to set the values with `->bind_param()` before calling `->execute()` (which does not take any parameters).

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO renter (email, msg_text) VALUES(?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['msg_text']);
$stmt->execute();
```

See documentation and example on the PHP official site : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php