# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C Stack trace: #0 require() #1 {main} thrown in C on line 31

Tags: php

I get this error above, My code is as below. Anything wrong with my code? tq. I'm not sure if it has something to do with changing to a different version of PHP.

```
<?php
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        header("Location: error104.php");
        die();
    }
    $reclimit=3;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=$_GET['page'];}
    else
    {
    $page=1;
    }
    $start=(($page-1)*$reclimit);
    $advert = "SELECT * FROM useriklan AS ua INNER JOIN users AS u ON  ua.id=u.id
    WHERE u.id='".$id."'";
    $result=$conn->query($advert);
    $total=$result->num_rows;
    $tpages=ceil($total/$reclimit);
    //pagination script ends here
    $advert = "SELECT * FROM useriklan AS ua INNER JOIN users AS u ON  ua.id=u.id
    WHERE u.id='".$id."' ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT $start,$reclimit";
    //$statement = $conn->query($advert);
    $statement = $conn->prepare($advert);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: In one of your sql strings, the table is named `useriklan` and the other is `useraiklan`. Is one of them wrong?

Comment: oh, ok. I already changed it but I still get the same error. thank you by the way for noticing it.  Both are now useriklan.

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing the value of `$statement`. If preparing the statement doesn't work, then the value will be set to false (hence the boolean) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to a member function execute() on boolean in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132451/call-to-a-member-function-execute-on-boolean-in)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to unpack in your code, especially when it comes to security, parameters etc.

## Debugging

First of all when you're using `mysqli` and you're debugging, you should add the error flags as follows at the top of your file.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

This will give you useful info to understand what's wrong with your statements.

## Prepared statements

The beauty of prepared statements (the `prepare` method you use your in query) is that they take care of adding your parameters in a safe way, protecting you from sql injection among other things.

So you should use `bind_param` to add your variables (e.g. `$id`). For example in your first query

```
$advert = "SELECT * FROM useriklan AS ua INNER JOIN users AS u ON  ua.id=u.id
    WHERE u.id= ?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($advert);
$statement->bind_param('s', $id);
```

In case `$id` is a number (`integer`), you can be more strict and use the `i`' type instead of `s` as follows.

```
$statement->bind_param('i', $id);
```

You can do the same on the second query

```
$advert = "SELECT * FROM useriklan AS ua INNER JOIN users AS u ON  ua.id=u.id WHERE u.id= ? ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT ?,?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($advert);
$statement->bind_param('iii', $id, $start, $reclimit);
```

## Missing `$id` definition

The variable `$id` is nowhere to be found in your code. I assume you meant `$_SESSION['id']` so you can do something like

```
$id = $_SESSION['id']
```